# Why this if only run ones?

Tags: python-3.x

### `I want the code keep repeat the subtract 1000 until a will be < 1000,

### Thanks for reply.

## This is a code  I tried:`

```
a = 10749

if a > 1000:
    a = a - 1000
    print(a)
```

Comment: When you say "repeat", you need to use a loop, but not the 'if' statement. In your case, a 'while' loop would be the suitable one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you want to **repeat** an operation, you have to use a **loop**. In python, you have for loops and while loops (you can take a look at the difference [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/for-while-loops-python/)).

Your code could be rewritten as:

```
a = 10749

while a > 1000:
    a = a - 1000
    print(a)
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys but while will print all the answers ,

Comment: 9749
8749
7749
6749
5749
4749
3749
2749
1749
749
 I only need to print 749

Comment: Move `print(a)` outside of the loop.